# Fragments don't get persisted on orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments

I use drop-down navigation, and due to some theming issues, I use a Spinner for it. I use the following method to set up the Actionbar:

```
public void setupActionBar() {
    Spinner navSpinner = new Spinner(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.Theme_Apptheme_Widget_ActionBarSpinner));
    navSpinner.setSelection(getSharedPreferences(APP_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).getInt(SELECTED_POSITION, 0));
    Log.d(getClass().getName(), navSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition() + "");
    navSpinner.setAdapter(new ActionBarSpinnerAdapter(getActionBar().getThemedContext(), dataSource.getAllShoppingLists()));
    navSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            if (position < dataSource.getAllShoppingLists().size()) {
                if(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("shoppinglist" + position) == null) {
                    ShoppingListFragment shoppingListFragment = ShoppingListFragment.
                            newInstance(dataSource.getShoppingListForPosition(position).getId());
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, shoppingListFragment, "shoppinglist" + position);
                    }
            } else if (position == dataSource.getAllShoppingLists().size()) {
                if(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("shoppinglistmanager") == null) {
                    ShoppingListManagerFragment shoppingListFragment = ShoppingListManagerFragment.newInstance();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, shoppingListFragment, "shoppinglistmanager");
                }
            }
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(APP_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            preferences.edit().putInt(SELECTED_POSITION, position).commit();
        }
    });

    getActionBar().setCustomView(navSpinner);
}
```

I call `setRetainInstance(true);` on the `Fragment`'s `onCreate()`, but still the Fragments are not being persisted. I check this by having and EditText and inputting text to it. Why is this happening?

Comment: How are you stepping away from the Fragment? Are you destroying the Activity?

Comment: @yiati I am rotating the device

Comment: Where does the variable datasource come from? It is likely that the ids are that you are receiving from it are not what you want. Also an alternative to using the ids to restore fragments is to use [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) and [onViewStateRestored](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewStateRestored(android.os.Bundle)) from the Fragment class to save primitive values, and use them to recreate the fragment.

Comment: @yiati is is created on onCreate. dataSource = new ShoppingListDataSource(this); dataSource.open(); The Fragments should be able to be retained automatically.

Comment: Not too sure without other classes here such as ShoppingListDataSource, or the Fragments. Yes setRetainInstance does retain automatically the information within a fragment, but if you are not seeing them be restored, then you are either not manually restoring the state of the views, or you are working with the wrong Fragments.

Comment: @yiati The state of the views should be automatically restored too. I am sure I'm using the correct Fragment.

Comment: Have you assigned `android:id` to the `EditText`? Can you show the layout file or the code where `EditText` is being added?

Comment: @ManishMulimani it seems you are right. I did not have a id for the EditText, that fixed it. If you want go ahead and post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set an identifier for `EditText`, for the Android system to save and restore the views state.

From [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html):

> Note: In order for the Android system to restore the state of the
>   views in your activity, each view must have a unique ID, supplied by
>   the android:id attribute.

If you are using layout file, specify it via attribute `android:id` or if you are creating `EditText` using API, then use [View.setId](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId%28int%29).